Need help remembering an underground city novel
I vaguely remember this book from elementary school about this boy who ventures into an underground city to find his lost/missing brother. The boy was claustrophobic because of an accident in which he and his brother dug a tunnel into a gas pipeline in their neighbor's backyard. I think he entered the underground city through the sewers, but I could be wrong. I think the city had some kind of corrupt dictatorship in which the main antagonist (young adolescent male but older than protagonist i think) was the dictator. There was also a character who had built hidey holes all over the place and used them to escape, and was part of some sort of organized resistance.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover?

I probably read this like 5-8 years ago and probably would've found it at my local elementary school library. I have no idea what the cover or title were.

It's possible that this may be Gregor the Overlander by Suzanne Collins as per Novel (or maybe series) About a Hidden Urban Underground Civilization

Eleven-year-old Gregor is left home alone in his family's New York City apartment to watch his sisters and grandmother. When Gregor's baby sister Boots falls through an old air duct grate in the building's basement, he dives in after her. The two fall miles below into the Underland: a subterranean world home to humans with near-translucent skin, violet eyes, and silver hair; giant sentient bats, rodents, and insects; and an escalating conflict between the human kingdom of Regalia and the rats' King Gorger. They meet several "Underlanders", among them the human Regalians' crown princess Luxa, who is Gregor's age, her cousin Henry, aged 14, and the bats who are "bonded" to them as warrior allies. At first, Gregor wants only to return home, but when he is attacked by two rats during an escape attempt and saved by the Underlanders, he inadvertently brings the conflict between the two groups to a head.

Not matching, I don't see any reference to him being claustrophobic due to a gas pipe incident, and the primary antagonist of the first book is King Gorger, a giant rat.
